# sh: 1: ping: not found when running job from jenkins

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, containers

I have a python script where various ping check has been performed . The same py file runs perfectly when triggered locally , but when i run the job from jenkins after building docker image the below error comes up and ping check always return false.

sh: 1: ping: not found

Can someone help me why this error is coming, do I need to update dockerfile with some update or some jenkins configuration is required.

Updating docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
ADD jenkins_bot.py /jenkins_bot.py
ADD src /src
ADD config /config
ADD run_unit_tests.sh /run_unit_tests.sh
ADD utests /utests

WORKDIR /

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
    apt-get -qqy install ssh && \
    apt-get -qqy install build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python3-setuptools \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libxft-dev && \
    apt-get -qqy install python3-pip && \
    pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
#RUN sh run_unit_tests.sh
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Barsha , Please provide us your DockerFile

Comment: More likely it's because docker cant't have access to a network for pinging the destination , Have you connect your docker to a network (either the way of connecting && porting the container and pc and also EXPOSE ing the port in DockerFile ? [Networking in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: @itshosyn thanks for your suggestions, I have updated the Dockerfile.

Comment: `apt-get install -y iputils-ping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is missing from in the ubuntu base image. You can update your dockerfile as follows to install it:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
ADD jenkins_bot.py /jenkins_bot.py
ADD src /src
ADD config /config
ADD run_unit_tests.sh /run_unit_tests.sh
ADD utests /utests

WORKDIR /

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y iputils-ping && \
    apt-get -qqy install ssh && \
    apt-get -qqy install build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python3-setuptools \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libxft-dev && \
    apt-get -qqy install python3-pip && \
    pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
#RUN sh run_unit_tests.sh
```